# Data type of time_Span and time in Ada

Tags: time, ada

What is the data type of time and time_span in Ada language. And how the variables of this type are stored in memory?

Comment: Why do you want to know? (it would make a difference to the answer)

Comment: I want to know how are they stored in memory?

Comment: Example: How Ada.Real_Time.Time_Span := Ada.Real_Time.Milliseconds(3) is stored in memory?

Comment: What I meant was, why do you need to know how they are stored in memory? If it’s just curiosity, OK, but if you need to pass them to another language on one machine, or to another system over the net, things get more complicated.

Comment: I am debugging an issue where I am checking the period of a CAN message which is further used to find out if the CAN rate is correct or not?

Comment: Can you just give me an example of any time duration stored in memory?

Comment: Sorry, I don’t see how I can say more than is already at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just looking at `Ada.Real_Time.Time_Span`, [ARM D.8(5)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-D-8.html#p4) says `type Time_Span is private;` and then [(17)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-D-8.html#p17) says the full declaration isn't defined by the language.

Further, [(20)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-D-8.html#p20) says

> Values of the type Time_Span represent length of real time duration.

[(31)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-D-8.html#p31) says

> Time_Span_First shall be no greater than –3600 seconds, and Time_Span_Last shall be no less than 3600 seconds.

and those statements are all that a portable Ada program can rely on.

Now, **specifically for GNAT**, we can look at the actual implementation on [Github](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/ada/libgnarl/a-reatim.ads#L151), where [in the private part we find](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/ada/libgnarl/a-reatim.ads#L151)

```
--  Time and Time_Span are represented in 64-bit Duration value in
--  nanoseconds. For example, 1 second and 1 nanosecond is represented
--  as the stored integer 1_000_000_001. This is for the 64-bit Duration
--  case, not clear if this also is used for 32-bit Duration values.

type Time is new Duration;

Time_First : constant Time := Time'First;

Time_Last  : constant Time := Time'Last;

type Time_Span is new Duration;
```

(note, this is for the desktop system: for embedded systems the types and values may be different).

So the answer is, **on desktop GNAT**, that `Time` and `Time_Span` are both stored as 64-bit values with least significant bit 1 nanosecond.

Answer (score 1):

There is defined a type named `Time` in the [Language Reference Manual](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-TOC.html).  The memory layout of this type is implementation defined.

Answer (score 1):

From [Ada Reference Manual](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-TOC.html)

- A value of the type Time in package Calendar, or of some other time type, represents a time as reported by a corresponding clock.
- Values of the type Time_Span represent length of real time duration.

In short terms Time type represent timestamp, Time_Span type represent duration of time period.